# is there a difference between the function y=x/x and the function y=1.

Tags: education

I have been asking people and have been getting mixed answers. some people think it is the same because when you simplify the first one you get y=1, but some people think that they are different because in the first equation x cannot be 0, and in the second equation x can be 0. Please tell me.

Comment: $x/x$ is not defined for $x=0$.

Comment: I knew that already it was in the description

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An expression alone is not a function. A function needs to have a domain specified. On the domain $\Bbb R\setminus \{0\}$ (or any subset thereof), they are the same function. On the domain $\Bbb R$, $\frac xx$ is not a function.

Comment: It’s worth noting that the reason $\frac{x}{x}$ is not a function on $\mathbb{R}$ is that a function must be defined on all of its domain.

Comment: so what you are saying is that this is not a function because not for a function y must be defined for all x???

Comment: @datboi By definition, yes, functions must have a value for every point in its domain.